# Lightweight rest how to do clickable results?

Tags: rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .net core.
And I'm in a situation where I must keep CPU usage to a bare minimum.
So I got interested in a lightweight web /rest possibilities.
And started new web api project and adjusted the default valuesControllers.cs

The situation is that I got lots of logfiles, I already can list logs by uri
  **localhost:someport/api/values/**
And i can show a simple txt log file content by typing
  **localhost:someport/api/values/5**
That will show the fith logfile content

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace Restview.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    const string LogFolder = @"C:\Logger\IOCount";
    String[] result =  Directory.GetFiles(LogFolder);

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<result.Length;i++) result[i]=Path.GetFileName(result[i]);
        return result;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(result[id]);
        string answer = "Showing : " + result[id] + "\n" + string.Join('\n',lines);
        return answer;
    }
  }
}
```

What i would like is that the results from **localhost:someport/api/values/** would get clickable, So if you click on a certain line you get to see that logfile as if **localhost:someport/api/values/clickedindex** was typed. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your Get() method into something like this:

```
// GET api/values
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<html><body>");

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append($"<div><a href='{Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { Action = "", id = i })}'>{Path.GetFileName(result[i])}</div>");
    }

    sb.Append("</body></html>");

    var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    res.Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

    return res;
}
```

As you can see if you want list, you would have to use html as output content type.

Comment: hmm can that also be optional HTML output and JSON raw data output by setting some kind of bracket option ea [HttpGet]  [JsonGet] ??

Comment: It is called "Content negotiation", you can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx), also all you may have is to use some query parameter like "?xml" for an xml output, and html output will be used as default or vice versa.